# Livy starts throwing java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, netty, amazon-emr, livy

I am working with EMR 6.2.0 and livy 0.7.0

I have a worker which keeps launching spark sessions and polling for its completion. This **runs fine for a while** but then suddenly Livy starts throwing

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:88)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47)
        at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:77)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:72)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:59)
        at org.apache.livy.rsc.RSCClient.<init>(RSCClient.java:81)
        at org.apache.livy.rsc.RSCClientFactory.createClient(RSCClientFactory.java:76)
        at org.apache.livy.LivyClientBuilder.build(LivyClientBuilder.java:130)
        at org.apache.livy.server.interactive.InteractiveSession$.$anonfun$create$1(InteractiveSession.scala:111)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
        at org.apache.livy.server.interactive.InteractiveSession$.create(InteractiveSession.scala:81)
        at org.apache.livy.server.interactive.InteractiveSessionServlet.createSession(InteractiveSessionServlet.scala:55)
        at org.apache.livy.server.interactive.InteractiveSessionServlet.createSession(InteractiveSessionServlet.scala:40)
        at org.apache.livy.server.SessionServlet.$anonfun$new$16(SessionServlet.scala:139)
        at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase.liftAction(ScalatraBase.scala:280)
        at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase.$anonfun$invoke$1(ScalatraBase.scala:274)
        at org.scalatra.ApiFormats.withRouteMultiParams(ApiFormats.scala:183)
        at org.scalatra.ApiFormats.withRouteMultiParams$(ApiFormats.scala:169)
        at org.apache.livy.server.JsonServlet.withRouteMultiParams(JsonServlet.scala:39)
        at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase.invoke(ScalatraBase.scala:273)
        at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase.invoke$(ScalatraBase.scala:272)
        at org.apache.livy.server.JsonServlet.invoke(JsonServlet.scala:39)
        at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase.$anonfun$runRoutes$3(ScalatraBase.scala:248)
        at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:271)
        at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase.$anonfun$runRoutes$1(ScalatraBase.scala:246)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.flatMap(Stream.scala:493)
        at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase.runRoutes(ScalatraBase.scala:245)
        at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase.runRoutes$(ScalatraBase.scala:243)
        at org.apache.livy.server.JsonServlet.runRoutes(JsonServlet.scala:39)
        at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase.runActions$1(ScalatraBase.scala:169)
        at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase.$anonfun$executeRoutes$6(ScalatraBase.scala:181)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase.cradleHalt(ScalatraBase.scala:199)
        at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase.executeRoutes(ScalatraBase.scala:181)
        at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase.executeRoutes$(ScalatraBase.scala:150)
        at org.apache.livy.server.JsonServlet.executeRoutes(JsonServlet.scala:39)
        at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase.$anonfun$handle$1(ScalatraBase.scala:123)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
        at org.scalatra.DynamicScope.withResponse(DynamicScope.scala:79)
        at org.scalatra.DynamicScope.withResponse$(DynamicScope.scala:77)
        at org.apache.livy.server.JsonServlet.withResponse(JsonServlet.scala:39)
        at org.scalatra.DynamicScope.$anonfun$withRequestResponse$1(DynamicScope.scala:59)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
        at org.scalatra.DynamicScope.withRequest(DynamicScope.scala:70)
        at org.scalatra.DynamicScope.withRequest$(DynamicScope.scala:68)
        at org.apache.livy.server.JsonServlet.withRequest(JsonServlet.scala:39)
        at org.scalatra.DynamicScope.withRequestResponse(DynamicScope.scala:58)
        at org.scalatra.DynamicScope.withRequestResponse$(DynamicScope.scala:56)
        at org.apache.livy.server.JsonServlet.withRequestResponse(JsonServlet.scala:39)
        at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase.handle(ScalatraBase.scala:123)
        at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase.handle$(ScalatraBase.scala:119)
        at org.apache.livy.server.JsonServlet.org$scalatra$servlet$ServletBase$$super$handle(JsonServlet.scala:39)
        at org.scalatra.servlet.ServletBase.handle(ServletBase.scala:53)
        at org.scalatra.servlet.ServletBase.handle$(ServletBase.scala:46)
        at org.apache.livy.server.SessionServlet.org$scalatra$MethodOverride$$super$handle(SessionServlet.scala:45)
        at org.scalatra.MethodOverride.handle(MethodOverride.scala:35)
...skipping...
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected client ID '40f2d9b7-6460-45b1-9521-6a92ff733766' in SASL handshake.
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at org.apache.livy.rsc.Utils.checkArgument(Utils.java:42)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at org.apache.livy.rsc.rpc.RpcServer$SaslServerHandler.update(RpcServer.java:288)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at org.apache.livy.rsc.rpc.SaslHandler.channelRead0(SaslHandler.java:61)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at org.apache.livy.rsc.rpc.SaslHandler.channelRead0(SaslHandler.java:36)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:295)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageCodec.channelRead(ByteToMessageCodec.java:103)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream: 21/02/05 14:15:57 WARN DefaultChannelPipeline: An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected client ID '40f2d9b7-6460-45b1-9521-6a92ff733766' in SASL handshake.
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at org.apache.livy.rsc.Utils.checkArgument(Utils.java:42)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at org.apache.livy.rsc.rpc.RpcServer$SaslServerHandler.update(RpcServer.java:288)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at org.apache.livy.rsc.rpc.SaslHandler.channelRead0(SaslHandler.java:61)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at org.apache.livy.rsc.rpc.SaslHandler.channelRead0(SaslHandler.java:36)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:295)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageCodec.channelRead(ByteToMessageCodec.java:103)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
21/02/05 14:15:57 INFO LineBufferedStream:      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
21/02/05 14:15:58 WARN ContextLauncher: Child process exited with code 1.
21/02/05 14:15:58 ERROR rejectedExecution: Failed to submit a listener notification task. Event loop shut down?
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.reject(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:821)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.offerTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:327)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.addTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:320)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:746)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.safeExecute(DefaultPromise.java:760)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:428)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:122)
        at org.apache.livy.rsc.ContextLauncher$ChildProcess.fail(ContextLauncher.java:417)
        at org.apache.livy.rsc.ContextLauncher$ChildProcess.access$1100(ContextLauncher.java:369)
        at org.apache.livy.rsc.ContextLauncher$ChildProcess$1.run(ContextLauncher.java:400)
        at org.apache.livy.rsc.ContextLauncher$ChildProcess$2.run(ContextLauncher.java:451)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

There aren't a lot of concurrent sessions running as well. At most 5 sessions running concurrently. All the older sessions are deleted by the worker once the job is completed to ensure not too many sessions are open at one time.

And the bad part is that it doesn't recover automatically after worker stops creating new sessions. Only works after the livy server is restarted.